# How to draw 3D dynamic curve with python

Tags: python

I continue to output three-dimensional coordinates, and use these coordinates to output three-dimensional dynamic curves. Here is my code, but there is nothing in the figure.

```
plt.ion()  
x = [0]
y = [0]
z = [0]
x_now = 0
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.axes(projection='3d')

for i in range(50):
    plt.clf() 
    x_now = i * 1
    x.append(x_now)
    y.append(x_now)
    z.append(x_now)
    ax1.scatter3D(x, y, z) 
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`plt.clf()` will clear the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0]
y = [0]
z = [0]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
for i in range(5):
    x_now = i * 1
    x.append(x_now)
    y.append(x_now)
    z.append(x_now)    
    ax.scatter(x, y, z)
    plt.pause(0.1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you launch this script? If it is `jupyter-notebook`, add this line on top:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

If you are using `jupyter-console`, it will be

```
%matplotlib <backend>
```

where `<backend>` is one of (`'osx', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'gtk3', 'notebook', 'wx', 'qt', 'nbagg`).

If it is a regular script, first you should do:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('<backend>') #in quotes
```

where `<backend>` is:

```
- interactive backends:
  GTK3Agg, GTK3Cairo, MacOSX, nbAgg,
  Qt4Agg, Qt4Cairo, Qt5Agg, Qt5Cairo,
  TkAgg, TkCairo, WebAgg, WX, WXAgg, WXCairo

- non-interactive backends:
  agg, cairo, pdf, pgf, ps, svg, template
```

Then you are importing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and go on with your script.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm using pycharm

Comment: @littlefirewooder So it's a "regular script" in my answer. If it works, don't forget to upvote and mark solved.